# Как добавить свой config в Nginx на Open Server?

Tags: nginx, openserver

Привет! Подскажите как добавить свой конфиг в Nginx на Open Server?
Есть строки конфига, не могу понять как создать файл конфигурации nginx в папке соответствующего сайта...